# How to open a jquery tab from a link that is outside the tab?

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, tabs, hyperlink

I have found a nice tabs system ([link](http://www.cssjunction.com/tutorials/jquery-tabs-too-easy-to-create-a-bit-jquery-a-bit-css/) to the tab system) on the internet to let the users navigate through my website. However I am not that good in coding. I have somehow managed to get things working.

I am trying/ tweaking for two days to get it working. Recording to this code I would be able to make a link that will open a specified tab. How could you make a link that -when clicked on it- would open the specified tab.

This code will do the trick but do not know how to implement this code in my existing Javascript code.

CODE:

```
var $tabs = $('#example').tabs(); // first tab selected

$('#my-text-link').click(function() { // bind click event to link
    $tabs.tabs('select', 2); // switch to third tab
    return false;
});
```

Found this code at this [website](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/API/1.8/Tabs#...open_links_in_the_current_tab_instead_of_leaving_the_page)

HTML CODE:

```
<div id="tabs">

    <ul>
        <li><a class="active" href="#tab1">HOME</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab2">SERVICES</a></li>
        <li><a href="#tab3">OPTIONS</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab4">ABOUT US</a></li>
            <li><a href="#tab5">CONTACT US</a></li>
    </ul><!-- //Tab buttons -->

    <div class="tabDetails">
        <div id="tab1" class="tabContents">
                <h1>Title1</h1>
                <iframe src="Home.html" width="1150" height="600" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Browser not compatible. </iframe >
        </div><!-- //tab1 -->
        <div id="tab2" class="tabContents">
                <h1>Title2  </h1>
                <h2>  </h2>
                <h3>  </h3>
                <iframe src="Services.html" width="1150" height="640" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Browser not compatible. </iframe >
        </div><!-- //tab2 -->
        <div id="tab3" class="tabContents">
               <h1>Title3</h1>
               <iframe src="Options.html" width="1150" height="600" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Browser not compatible. </iframe >
        </div><!-- //tab3 -->
        <div id="tab4" class="tabContents">
            <h1>Title4 </h1>
            <iframe src="Aboutus.html" width="1150" height="600" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Browser not compatible. </iframe >
        </div><!-- //tab4 -->
        <div id="tab5" class="tabContents">
            <h1>Title5</h1>
           <iframe src="Contactus.html" width="1150" height="600" frameBorder="0" scrolling="no">Browser not compatible. </iframe >
        </div><!-- //tab5 -->
    </div><!-- //tab Details -->
</div><!-- //Tab Container -->
```

CSS:

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>jQuery Tab</title>
<style type="text/css">
*{margin:10; padding:0;}

body{

    font:normal 14px/1.5em Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}
a{outline:none;}

#tabs{
    background:#f0f0f0;
    border:1x solid #fff;
    margin:100px auto;
    padding:20px;
    position:absolute;
    width:1315px;
}
    #tabs ul{
        overflow:hidden;
        border-left:0px solid #fff;
        height:80px;
        position:center;
        z-index:100;
    }
    #tabContaier li{
        float:left;
        list-style:none;
    }
    #tabs li a{
        background:#ddd;
        border:3px solid #ffff;
        border-left:0;
        color:#666;
        cursor:pointer;
        display:block;
        height:35px;
        line-height:35px;
        padding:0 98px;
        text-decoration:none;
        text-transform:bold;
    }
    #tabs li a:hover{
        background:#fff;
    }
    #tabs li a.active{
        background:#fbfbfb;
        border:px solid #fff;
        border-right:px;
        color:#333;
    }
    .tabDetails{
        background:#fbfbfb;
        border:1px solid #fff;
        margin:34px px;
    }
    .tabContents{
        padding:px

}
    .tabContents h1{
        font:normal 24px/1.1em Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        padding:0 0 px;
                                width:auto;



</style>
```

JAVASCRIPT CODE:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.7.2.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){

$( ".selector" ).tabs( "refresh" );

    // Hide all tab conten divs by default
    $(".tabContents").hide(); 

    // Show the first div of tab content by default
    $(".tabContents:first").show(); 

    //Fire the click event
    $("#tabContaier ul li a").click(function(){ 

        // Catch the click link
        var activeTab = $(this).attr("href"); 

        // Remove pre-highlighted link
        $("#tabContaier ul li a").removeClass("active"); 

        // set clicked link to highlight state
        $(this).addClass("active");         

        // hide currently visible tab content div
        $(".tabContents").hide(); 

        // show the target tab content div by matching clicked link.
        $(activeTab).fadeIn(); 
 return false;


    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see where you include the JQuery UI script - what version of JQuery UI are you using?

Comment: @WebChemist What do you mean by that, sorry for my lack of knowledge. But I have found this code on the internet. I have provided a url to the website where the tabs system is located

Comment: its not enough to just have JQuery, for tabs you also need the JQuery UI js file. If you don't know what I mean then sounds like you arent including the necessary jquery-ui file

Comment: Here is a working fiddle of the example you wanted: [LINK HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/aaaheatair/LTWMm/)

Comment: @WebChemist... You do not HAVE TO HAVE jQuery UI to make tabs in jQuery. You can write your own.

Comment: @Roy, his initial code said he wanted to use .tabs() which requires the UI (or reimplementing a tab() plugin yourself). I realize it's possible to make tabs from scratch, but why reinvent the wheel?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem was you were selecting the tab with a different jquery tab. Use this Javascript function to change the selected tab.

```
function selectTab(tabIndex) {
    var selector = "a[href='#tab" + tabIndex + "']";
    var tab = "#tab" + tabIndex;
    $("#tabContaier ul li a").removeClass("active");
    $(selector).addClass("active");
    $(".tabContents").hide();
    $(tab).fadeIn();
}
```

Link:

```
<a href="#" onclick="selectTab(2);" >Go to tab 2</a>
```

This will work if you use the same link nomenclature as you are using now (href for links as "tab1, tab2" etc, and the divs named "tab1, tab2" etc...
Good luck.

Comment: I have done this: 

Added the code after this line 
$(document).ready(function(){

var $tabs = $('#tabs').tabs(); // first tab selected

$('#my-text-link').click(function() { // bind click event to link
    $tabs.tabs('select', 2); // switch to second tab
    return false;
});

added this line for the link:
<a href="#my-text-link">Tab 2</a>

But it seems it is not working the url in my browser changes to index.html#my-text-link and the layout of the tabs are suddenly changed

Comment: No it is not working I don't know how to fix this (I doing obviously something wrong) could you edit for me the code and give me an example. It is really frustrating because I have been searching more than two days for the solution. I am really bad in coding..

Comment: Thank you in advance for your support.

Comment: I have updated the answer. Try that function to change your selected tab.

Comment: @AD12 a working fiddle of your script is [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/aaaheatair/LTWMm/2/)

Comment: @Hanlet Escaño 
You are a hero man thanx allot you have saved me from allot of frustration, extra searching and tweaking.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're over-complicating this and trying to recreate the actions of the JQuery UI tabs. You can eliminate all but the inital tabs creation and the click event. The only part of the other JS you have posted that might actually do anything is the `fadeIn()` As for styling, don't assign and remove the active class, use the `.ui-tabs-active` class. Style the background color of the li, not the a or your a style will override the li.ui-tabs-active and they will stay grey even on hover/selection. See example here:

See fiddle demo here: http://jsfiddle.net/webchemist/Dpg2W/

Also you have some CSS errors:

```
 #tabs li a.active{
        background:#fbfbfb;
        border:px solid #fff;
        border-right:px; /*no numeric value given for # of pixels*/
        color:#333;
}

.tabDetails{
        background:#fbfbfb;
        border:1px solid #fff;
        margin:34px px; /*no numeric value given for # of pixels in 2nd value*/
}

.tabContents{
        padding:px /*no numeric value given for # of pixels*/
}

.tabContents h1{
        font:normal 24px/1.1em Georgia, "Times New Roman", Times, serif;
        padding:0 0 px;
                                width:auto;

/*no closing brace for .tabContents h1*/

</style>
```

Comment: thanx for the effort you put in this issue trying to solve the problem, but Hanlet Escaño has come with the right solution that is really dealing the problem that I had more than two days.