# How can I show a specific content in a page according to the link the user use?

Tags: php, wordpress

I have made a page with some posts stored by category in some tabs in the page and I want to arrive directly on a specific tab of the page according to the link the user use in another page.
I have these tabs :

```
<div class="tab">
      <button class="tablinks" id="defaultOpen" onclick="openCity(event, 'Tout voir')">Tout voir</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Ingénieur DevOps')">Ingénieur DevOps</button>
      <button class="tablinks" onclick="openCity(event, 'Ingénieur Big Data')">Ingénieur Big Data</button>
</div>
```

By default the content of the first button is show (#defaultOpen).
But I dont know to do this, maybe by the URL ?
And after I need to do a script that automatically click on the category I want (like the first button by default).
How can I do this? TY.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

not sure if i did understand it right but maybe this will help you:

[How to open a jquery tab from a link that is outside the tab?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14570267/how-to-open-a-jquery-tab-from-a-link-that-is-outside-the-tab)

or this:

https://forum.jquery.com/topic/how-to-open-a-specific-tab-via-an-external-link